# Maximum Number of Selections MultiSelectListPreference Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there any way to set the maximum number of selections for a MultiSelectListPreference in Android? I only want the user to be able to select 5 values maximum. Here is my xml so far:

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
        android:key="user_interests"
        android:title="interests"
        android:entries="@array/interests_array"
        android:entryValues="@array/interests_values"
        android:defaultValue="@array/interests_default_values" />
```

If it would be easier to get more complex functionality out of a separate Fragment, I'd be happy to use that instead; although I'm not sure how to start a fragment from the PreferenceScreen xml; I tried android:Fragment but to no avail.